# Python 2.x minidom: How do I set a unicode codec?

Tags: python, unicode, minidom

How do I configure a minidom instance to have a unicode codec?

Processing this snippet in an XML file:

```
<title type="text">ME850单片机开发实验仪(增强配置)(产品浏览)-伟纳电子-http://www.willar.com/</title>
```

produces this error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 5-12: ordinal not in range(128)
```

update: works as expected in Python 3; apparently this is a known limitation of 2.x.

Comment: XML is UTF-8 usually, not Unicode. Encode to UTF-8 before passing it to minidom?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python 2.x, minidom can only parse byte strings. Either don't decode your document in the first place <sub>(hint: a more specific suggestion would require the code you're running)</sub>, or encode it into UTF-8.

Alternatively, you can switch to Python 3.x, where minidom can handle bytes as well as character strings.

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
str.encode('utf-8')
```